# Simples Nacional The ControlToValidate property of ''RegularExpressionValidator1'' cannot be blank

Tags: html, delphi, query

Estou desenvolvendo uma consulta no Simples Nacional, mas ao dar um HTTPPost no site http://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br/simplesnacional/aplicacoes/atbhe/consultaoptantes.app/consultaropcao.aspx me retorna o erro

```
The ControlToValidate property of ''RegularExpressionValidator1'' cannot be blank.
```

Segue o Código da consulta:

```
Post.WriteString('__EVENTTARGET='); {Se comento esta linha, me retorna em branco}
Post.WriteString('__EVENTARGUMENT=');
Post.WriteString('__VIEWSTATE=' + FViewState);
Post.WriteString('__EVENTVALIDATION=' + FEventValidation);
Post.WriteString('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo$' + FSessao + '=' + OnlyNumber(ACNPJ));
Post.WriteString('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo$HiddenField1=' + FSessao);
Post.WriteString('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo$hddServidorCaptcha=pro');
Post.WriteString('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo$txtTexto_captcha_serpro_gov_br=' + ACaptcha);
Post.WriteString('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo$btnConfirmar=Consultar');
Post.WriteString('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_RegularExpressionValidator1=null');
Post.Position := 0;

HttpSend.Clear;
HttpSend.Document.Position := 0;
HttpSend.Document.CopyFrom(Post, Post.Size);
HTTPSend.MimeType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
HTTPPost('http://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br/simplesnacional/aplicacoes/atbhe/consultaoptantes.app/consultaropcao.aspx');
```

Alguém sabe o porque do erro? Como posso corrigir?

Comment: Já tentou passar alguma expressão regular aqui neste comando ao invés de **NULL**?? `Post.WriteString('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_RegularExpressionValidator1=null');`

Comment: Estava olhando o código na depuração da página de consulta e vi que parece que algo não está batendo. Tente essas 3 alternativas pra testar se alguma funciona.

Post.WriteString('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_RegularExpressionValidator1');
Post.WriteString('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_RegularExpressionValidator1.validationexpression="\\d+"');
Post.WriteString('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_RegularExpressionValidator1="\\d+"'); *Esta conforme sugerido pelo Matheus.